# Need to make available libs not available inside existing docker image

Tags: docker

I have a docker image that is 20G large. I will need this image to do all my stuff. But I require more libraries, not available in it.
I do not want to install python packages in the system, rather would prefer installing them in a virtual env on the host or within the docker container.
virtual environment would be a good choice as I could benefit from using host system libs using "--system-site-packages" (eg, OpenCV).
I need the flexibility to change my libraries, so if building an image from the 20G image takes time or huge disk space then it is not my preferred solution.
I will not be running any app using CMD because I will be using the container to run/develop stuffs using the terminal from within the container.

I have checked existing solutions and all of them suggest creating new docker image using some base docker image. Moreover my requirements are not fulfilled. I am not an expert in Docker.

Comment: 2GB is large, 20GB sounds excessive. Are you putting large amounts of working data into the image? Maybe, mounting that working data as a volume would be a better approach. That said, if you need a tool inside the container, you typically put it into the image, but of course you can also install it in the running container instead. In any case, your use case seems odd, but it's unclear what you're doing, so maybe you elaborate a bit on the topic.

Comment: I'm using a prebuilt image which is 20.5G and it is using another base image which is 246M.